# How can I let one JavaScript function run for every value in a PHP array continuously?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have to design an auctioning website where I want to set the status of specific auctions to 'Closed' in a SQL database when the endingtime has passed. I am stuck how I can make sure that I run a Javascript function for each element in a PHP array. If I use a foreach I assume it just continuously runs for the first element in the array, as the function has to check constantly if the endingtime has not passed. This is what I have now:

```
$timings=array();
$sql = "SELECT endingtime,auctID,state from auctions ";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

   if($row[0]-time()<=0 and $row[2]=='Open'){ 
                        $timings[]=$row[0];
                        };};}

foreach($timings as $value){

    echo "<script>


function Time() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var date = new Date($value);
    var difference = date - now;
    if (date-now <0){
    window.location = 'auc_timing_sql.php'};}

    setInterval(Time,1000);
</script>"
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As FoulFoot said, you'd need to have some sort of cronjob in order to constantly check.

There are some options you can choose:

**1) cronjob inside a JS script.**

Use NodeJS and some npm package that lets you use cron like [cron - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```js
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;

new CronJob(
    "1 * * * *",
    function() {
        /*
        Do your thing here, you can use some mysql package like mysql2 to access your db.
        */
    },
    null,
    true,
    "America/Los_Angeles"
);
```

**2) Linux's crontab**

Create a JS script and then put it under Linux's crontab.

```js
//myscript.js
const mysql = require("mysql2");
....
....
```

and then edit Linux's crontab using *crontab -e*

```sh
1 * * * * node path/to/myscript.js
```

Both of these examples checks **every minute**, you can go for 5minutes,10minutes and so on, here's crontab syntax: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Javascript isn't what you want here.  To do constantly rolling checks of auction endings, you'd need to run a server CRON job that executes a PHP script every minute or so.  Just make sure the script execution time is shorter than your CRON period, or you'll have collisions.